Is the product of a reversible lattice and a non-reversible lattice non-reversible?
I was messing around with lattice structures when I thought of this problem:
Let $L$ be a (bounded) lattice. $L$ is called reversible if there is a lattice isomorphism from $L$ to $L^c$ ($L^c$ being the lattice $L$ with the opposite ordering). Equivalently, $L$ is reversible if there exists an order-reversing bijection from $L$ to itself.
It is pretty clear that if $L_1$ and $L_2$ are reversible, so is the product lattice $L_1 \times L_2$. If neither are reversible, their product can either be reversible (if two assymetries cancel each other out, easiest example being $L \times L^c$ for any lattice $L$) or not.
However, I can't prove that if only $L_1$ is reversible, then $L_1 \times L_2$ has to not be, even though I think it's intuitively obvious, as $L_2$ introduces an asymmetry I do not think $L_1$ can "remove".
The difficulty I encountered trying to prove this comes from the fact that an order-reversing map from $L_1 \times L_2$ to itself does not have to be "nice" with respect to the coordinates, so I can't manipulate it into an order-reversing map from $L_2$ to itself.
Any help would be aprechiated. Note that the lattice structure might be unnecesary, I suspect any proof would work for general posets.

By the way, "reversible" is also called "self-dual" in the context of posets/lattices.

Regarding the "finite lattices" follow-up.. if everything is finite and we have $L_1 \times L_2 \cong L_1 \times L_2^C$, then I believe it follows from this that we must have $L_2 \cong L_2^C$, because lattices can be characterised algebraically (one must be a bit careful - you should just use axioms of not-necessarily-bounded lattices so the hypothesis is met, as then any singleton is a subalgebra). So there are no finite examples. I don't know about finite width at the moment.

@IzaakvanDongen I will take your word for it, because I am not familiar with universal algebra, but if that's true, that is wonderful news: My motivation for this problem was that I wanted to turn lattices with the product operation into a group by declaring two lattices $L_1$ and $L_2$ equivalent if $L_1 \times L_2^c$ is reversible/self-dual. While trying to formalize this the only main issue was, well, caused by this question.
If the hypothesis holds for finite lattices, then the set of all finite lattices under this equivalence relation turns into an abelian group.

@kabelabel I've just been shown an elementary proof of the same thing here https://mathoverflow.net/a/269545. You get from cancellativity of finite topologies to cancellativity of finite lattices via the Alexandrov topology.

@ZoeAllen Thank you! From this, it really appears that I stumbled upon something that is true for any category with a certain finiteness condition, which is fascinating.

Consider $L_1=(\omega+1)^\mathbb{N}\times ((\omega+1)^C)^\mathbb{N}$ and $L_2=\omega+1$
Then $L_1^C=((\omega+1)^C)^\mathbb{N}\times (\omega+1)^\mathbb{N} \cong (\omega+1)^\mathbb{N}\times ((\omega+1)^C)^\mathbb{N}$ by simply swapping the two parts, so $L_1$ is reversible. $L_2$ clearly isn't. But Their product is just isomorphic to $L_1$ again.
Hence $L_1 \times L_2$ can be reversible.

This is a really clever counter-example, I hadn't considered that many infinite lattices when looking for counter-examples.
Now I'm wondering if my hypothesis holds true for finite lattices where this trick cannot work. Obviously I accept your answer - I hadn't specified finiteness, but it's an interesting followup to consider.

Nice! I think technically this isn't bounded, right? But that can be arranged by using $\omega + 1$ instead, I believe. (I'm not totally sure what the parenthesised "bounded" means in the OP, but I thought I'd mention this)

@IzaakvanDongen oops I didn't notice it had to be bounded, thank you for your correction

@IzaakvanDongen I restriced it to bounded lattices (have a top and a bottom) because those were the types of lattices I was working with. But I don't think it changes anything because you can just artificially add a $0$ and a $1$ to any counterexample to create a bounded one (I think).

@kabelabel, I don't see immediately why that's true. If you artificially add a top and bottom to $L_1$ and $L_2$, then doesn't $L_1 \times L_2$ get "cross-terms" that look like $L_2$ in it? It's not obvious to me that this will preserve the reversibility of $L_1 \times L_2$ in general. I believe that in the "$\omega$ version" of this answer, something would in fact go wrong as $L_1 \times L_2$ has the property "there is some $x > 0$ such that $x > y$ implies $y = 0$", but its opposite doesn't. It's all academic anyway because Zoe's lovely idea was easy to modify!

@IzaakvanDongen You're correct, I forgot to consider the cross-terms (actually, I did consider them, but not hard enough).
Currently, I'm doing what any mathematician does when proven wrong: adding more criterion until I'm right.  The counterexample does not work if we restrict our attention to lattices of finite width, so I guess that's what I'll examine next.
